# Move the starting point of a line

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm drawing a straight line and I want to make it in such a way that when touch movement is small (e.g 10 pixel), the starting point(fromPoint) will follow the touch rather than staying at the first touch.

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

    CGPoint fromPoint;
    CGPoint toPoint;

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);
    CGColorSpaceRef colorspace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGFloat components[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    CGColorRef color = CGColorCreate(colorspace, components);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, color);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);

    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, fromPoint.x, fromPoint.y);
    CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, toPoint.x, toPoint.y);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorspace);
    CGColorRelease(color);

}


//touch event
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    fromPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    toPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    toPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    // ***** not working ******
    // when touch movement is small (e.g 10 pixel), the starting point will follow the touch rather than staying at the first touch 
    if (fabs(_draw.toPoint.x - _draw.fromPoint.x) < 10 && fabs(_draw.toPoint.y - _draw.fromPoint.x) < 10){

    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    fromPoint = [touch locationInView:self];
    toPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    };

    //************************//

    [self setNeedsDisplay];  

}


- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event { 

    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    toPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    [self setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

UPDATE: The purpose is to make a slight adjustment of the starting point, when a magnifying glass is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because unless you move your finger very fast, you aren't able to differentiate between small movements and big movements.

You could try starting a timer in touchesBegan, and use that to work out the speed of movement, from which you can set some parameters between a slow and a fast touch.

You could even use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` which will work out the velocity for you.

Comment: any reference/tutorial on how to get the speed of movement?